# Dynamically set the table column width according to observable value length

Tags: javascript, html, user-interface, knockout-2.0

I have a table column which its value is bounded to an observable.

```
<table style="width: 100%; padding-top: 10px; padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px">
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: myObservable"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I would like to set the *column width according to myObservable length*. How can I do it?

Comment: Have you tried Width : auto; ??

Comment: @Manjuboyz yep, didn't work